# How do I draw attention to an updated question?

Tags: discussion, questions, support

I noticed that new posted questions get attention very quickly. If I take some time to read the replies and try myself, new questions often arise. When I edit my original post to add my new questions, I find the updated post is very hard to get attention again, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986418/typeid-and-typeof-in-c).

How should I deal with it? The best way I can think of is to open a new post with my new questions, and if necessary there will be a link to my old post.

Comment: Jump up and down, waving your hands overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just updating your post, make sure you post a comment to that effect on the existing answers.  Since people are notified of comments to their answers, this will often bring them back to have another look.

Comment: Thank you Eric. It is a good idea. Then how to attract people that haven't replied yet?

Comment: @Tim - That's more difficult unfortunately, but editing the question and adding the comments should move it up the "active" list a bit which should draw a bit more attention.

Comment: Would it be all right if I post my new questions in a new post? Will this be regarded as duplicated and therefore the post get closed?

Comment: Yes, don't re-ask existing questions.

Comment: You _can_ ask follow up questions in a new question. Just don't post the exact same question twice.